# pytorch cuda out of memory while inferencing

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu, pytorch-lightning

I think this is a very basic question, my apologies as I am very new to pytorch. I am trying to find if an image is manipulated or not using MantraNet. After running 2-3 inferences I get the CUDA out of memory, then after restarting the kernel also I keep getting the same error: The error is given below:

*RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 616.00 MiB (GPU 0; 4.00 GiB total capacity; 1.91 GiB already allocated; 503.14 MiB free; 1.93 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch) If reserved memory is >> allocated memory try setting max_split_size_mb to avoid fragmentation.  See documentation for Memory Management and PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF*

The 'tried to allocate memory(here 616.00 MiB) keeps changing. I checked the GPU statistics and it shoots up while I try to do the inferencing. In tensorflow I know we can control the memory usage by defining an upper limit, is there anything similar in pytorch that one can try?

Comment: can you provide your inference code? Usually, when you do inference, you will want to do `with torch.no_grad():`. See https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.no_grad.html

Comment: @joe32140 Hey so I checked the inference code, I can see that the line of code you mentioned is used.
with torch.no_grad():
         final_output = model(im)

Comment: Hopefully, you're using batch size=1. You can try fp16/int8 inference if your GPU supports it. Or try a smaller model or smaller images size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So during inferencing for a single image I realized there was no way I was able to fit my image in the gpu which I was using, so after resizing the image to a particular value I was able to do the inferencing without facing any memory issue.